# When I finish my task of converting exchange rate , I want to return to the main menu that appears when I start the program

Tags: c#

I want to return to the main menu not restarting the program all over again to change the type of conversion .. Any help please ?
I will be thankful if somebody here helped me ..

```
using System;

namespace Assignment_1_Csharp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {      int choice;
            double val,EGP;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your Choice :\n 1- Dollar to EGP \n 2- EGP to Dollar  ");
            choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    double dollar;
                    Console.Write("Enter the Dollar Amount :");
                    dollar = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Enter the Dollar Exchange Rate :");
                    val = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    EGP = dollar * val;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} Dollar Equals {1} EGP", dollar, EGP);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.Write("Enter the EGP Amount :");
                    EGP = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Enter the Dollar Exchange Rate :");
                    val = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    dollar = EGP / val;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} EGP Equals {1} Dollars", EGP, dollar);
                    break;
               
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is using a do-while loop. The following code will run through the choice selection and conversion and then ask user to continue. If the selection is "y" then it will ask the user to choose again otherwise exit the main method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int choice;
    double val, EGP;
    string userSelection = "y";
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Choice :\n 1- Dollar to EGP \n 2- EGP to Dollar  ");
        choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                double dollar;
                Console.Write("Enter the Dollar Amount :");
                dollar = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter the Dollar Exchange Rate :");
                val = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                EGP = dollar * val;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Dollar Equals {1} EGP", dollar, EGP);
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.Write("Enter the EGP Amount :");
                EGP = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter the Dollar Exchange Rate :");
                val = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                dollar = EGP / val;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} EGP Equals {1} Dollars", EGP, dollar);
                break;

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Y to choose again...");
        userSelection = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    while (userSelection.ToLower() == "y");
}
```

You can change the text messages and selection to anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

After `Console.Readline()`, just add `Main(null)`.

Comment: There's no need to recurse when a simple loop will suffice. It's wreckless to show this to beginners in such a bare, unexplained manner, and a professor would probably dock points for it.

Comment: Uh, explain to me why is it "wreckless" to use recursion? It's the change that requires the least amount of code to solve the OP's question.

Comment: That's not what I said. I said it was wreckless to show this to beginners without explaining it. Using the "least amount of code" might be good when you're in a bind and you need to get a fix to production, but beginners (and let's admit that this is homework) can take suggestions like this blindly and do it without understanding the ramifications. There's no exit condition, and if you let it run long enough, it will result in a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: Admittedly, that would take a long time to overflow the default 1MB stack by recursing `Main`, but if someone blindly did this elsewhere because they learned it without explanation, it could happen sooner. Not understanding that was what they were doing, *"surprise!"* Pedagogically, it's a poor suggestion.

Comment: Then by all means, post an answer that will explain the intricacies of a tail recursive function and stack pushing to the OP. I was just trying to solve the immediate problem in the simplest way.

Comment: Furthermore, a professor surely did not give this assignment with the intention to use recursion because it's not intended to *teach* recursion, so a professor (or TA) would rightly dock points for doing this. For homework questions, it's important to respect the instructional nature of the assignment. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: There's no reason to post such an answer because the assignment is not about recursion.

Comment: How would you know the intent of the professor? I don't have a copy of the syllabus handy, but it could say something like "Chapter 2: Recursion" as easily as "Chapter 2: While Loops".

Comment: Assignments about recursion focus on problems that are better solved by recursion. Console applications that present menus don't fit into that mold.